# Conditional concatenate cell content across rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a worksheet with thousands of rows which contain a unique ID `A`, and one 3 different error codes `M`. Each individual ID may have 1, 2 or 3 errors. They will always be in the same order.

I have typed by hand and in `N` what the desired output is. I have written a formula like this one in cols `O, P, Q` with the text of the error:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Brand is not valid", M42), "") <> "", "Brand", "")
```

I tried something like this in `R` but it's not working correctly for obvious reasons. Is there a way to do this so that `R` looks like `N`?

```
=CONCATENATE(O42,"/", P42,"/",Q42)
```

If not possible to do with Excel formula, is there perhaps a VBA way?

[image: concat]

Comment: Will there always be 3 entries per unique ID, or up to 3 entries?

Comment: Your `CONCATENATE` formula is working properly, there just isn't any data in the other cells of the row (P42 & Q42 are blank) to give the desired results.

Comment: @FreeMan there can be 1, 2 or 3 errors per unique ID, with a random distribution

Comment: @CharlieRB right, I realize that. Can you think of a different way to do this perhaps?

Comment: Is there a way to get `O, P, & OEM` in the same column? Will they always be in that order; brand, product, OEM? Or could it be a different order?

Comment: The order will always be the same - Brand, Product, OEM, however, it may not necessarily _have_ a Brand to start with (for example rows 48-49 in screenshot), or even a Product (see row 41)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, took some head scratching, but I've got it:

Columns `O`, `P` & `Q` as you have them, titled `Brand`, `Product` & `OEM`. Turn the whole thing into a table with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> (not required, but handy, and my column `R` relies on it, but you can use column references if you want)

Column `R`:

```
=IF(LEN([Brand])>0,[Brand],IF(LEN([Product])>0,[Product],IF(LEN([OEM])>0,[OEM],"")))
```

Column `S`:

```
=IF(A2=A4,F2&"/"&F3&"/"&F4,IF(A2=A1,"",IF(A2=A3,F2&"/"&F3,F2)))
```

Unfortunately, it seems the only way to use table references to a different row is to use `Offset`, so to keep it simpler, I went back to cell references. That kinda negates the cool/handy factor of turning the whole thing into a table in the first place, but, whatever...

And... Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wow... I got an `Are you a bot?` CAPCHA to fill out after submitting that. Weird...

Comment: Now that I think about it, if we have bots producing answers like this, I say "Bring 'em on!"

Comment: that solution works beautifully, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I would start by optimizing your `O`, `P`, and `Q` formulas. 
You currently have

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Brand is not valid", M42), "") <> "", "Brand", "")
```

`IFERROR` is a great function for displaying a sanitized version
of a computed value that might be an error code;
I use it, and recommend it in answers on Super User, frequently. 
As you probably know,

- `IFERROR(calculated_value, default_value)`

is short for

- `IF(ISERROR(calculated_value), default_value, calculated_value)`

But using `IFERROR` to create a sanitized version of some value
*and then testing that value to do something conditionally*
is an unnecessarily awkward way of using `IFERROR`. 
The above formula can be simplified to

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Brand is not valid", M42)), "", "Brand")
```

And, as I’m sure you know, `SEARCH("Brand is not valid", M42)`
tests to see whether `M42` *contains* `Brand is not valid`. 
But, as long as Column `M` can contain only your three error strings,
this can be shortened to

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Brand", M42)), "", "Brand")
```

or simplified to

```
=IF(M42 = "Brand is not valid", "Brand", "")
```

---

OK, now I’ll make the `O`, `P`, and `Q` formulas a little more complicated:

- `O42` → `=IF($A42=$A41, O41, "") & IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Brand", $M42)), "", "Brand")`
- `P42` → `=IF($A42=$A41, P41, "") & IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Product", $M42)), "", "Product")`
- `Q42` → `=IF($A42=$A41, Q41, "") & IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("OEM", $M42)), "", "OEM")`

The formula for `O42` says,

> If this is the second or third row for this ID (Column `A`),
>   look at the cell above this one
>   (i.e., the Column `O` cell for the previous row) to see
>   whether we’ve already established that this thing has an invalid brand.  Also,
>   look at Column `M` for this row to see whether it is `Brand is not valid`. 
>   Then concatenate the results.

Since a unique ID will never be listed twice with the same error (right?),
these two sub-results will never both be non-empty,
so this is essentially doing an “OR”:

> Show a value of `Brand` if this row,
>   OR one of the previous row(s) for this ID, contains the invalid brand error.

This has the effect or dragging the `O`, `P`, and `Q` values
down to the last row for each ID:

[image]

Note that rows 41, 44, 47, and 49 each shows the short forms of all errors
that apply to their respective IDs in Columns `O`, `P`, and `Q`.

I’ve defined Column `R` the same way you did. 
See [Generate a comma-separated list of cell contents, excluding blanks](https://superuser.com/q/647716/150988)
for techniques to eliminate the unwanted slashes from this.

If having the desired concatenation only in rows 41, 44, 47, and 49
is good enough, you’re done.  Otherwise, define `N42` as

```
=IF($A22=$A23, N23, R22)
```

or

```
=IF($A22<>$A23, R22, N23)
```

This is almost exactly the same trick I used in Columns `O`, `P`, and `Q`,
but going in the opposite direction:

> If this is the last row for this ID (i.e., if this is row 41, 44, 47, or 49),
>   use the concatenation of the values from this row
>   (which is the complete collection of error codes for this ID). 
>   Otherwise, look at the cell below this one
>   (i.e., the Column `N` cell for the next row),
>   which will have the correct answer.

In other words, the desired values percolate up to the first row for each ID.

Comment: Very nice, I learned something today!

Comment: @Scott that's a great answer! Have you considered checking out the Code Review site? This kind of answer would definitely shine through there!

Comment: @FreeMan: I'm glad to help you learn something.  If you want more interesting information on Excel, search Super User for [microsoft-excel], [worksheet-function], and, if you're so inclined, [vba].  Of course, a lot of what you find will be dull and boring; some will be enigmatic and unexplained; and some will be outright wrong.  You may get best results by focusing on answers written by [these people](http://superuser.com/help/badges/109/microsoft-excel).