# How to select multiple strings based on multiple conditions using IF function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

To make things easier, please see the below image first

[image: 1]

I am trying to get the cell under `Which Event?` (H2 cell) to say which events they are invited to.

- Suppose the person is only invited to *Sanji*, *Wedding* and *Reception*, then I want the formula to just show *Sanji, Wedding & Reception*(on the H2 cell) only if the value is >=1
- If the value is 0 on *Vesvaar* and *Sanji* but is >=1 on *Wedding* and *Reception*, then I want it to only show *Wedding & Reception*
- If the value is 0 on *Vesvaar*, *Sanji*, *Reception* but it's >=1 on *Wedding*, then I want it to show *Wedding only*.

I hope I make sense?

I tried to use the following formula:

```
=IF((AND(D2>0,E2>0,F2>0,G2>0)),*All*,*Sanji, Wedding & Reception*)
```

Where if I put a 1 on *Vesvaar*, *Sanji*, *Wedding*, *Reception*, the cell H2 will change to *All events*. But if the value is 0 on *Vesvaar*, *Sanji*, *Reception* but it's >=1 on *Wedding*, then it doesn't work.

I really hope I made sense and that you're able to help me?

Comment: Related:  [Conditional concatenate cell content across rows](https://superuser.com/q/922843/150988) & [Generate a comma-separated list of cell contents, excluding blanks](https://superuser.com/q/647716/150988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way is to convert the list to binary and use `VLOOKUP` to find the events

```
=VLOOKUP((B2 > 0)*8 + (C2 > 0)*4 +(D2 > 0)*2 + (E2 > 0)*1, $H$2:$I$17, 2, FALSE)
```

The `cell > 0` part produces a boolean value that would be converted to 0 or 1 in an arithmetic expression. The columns from left to right represent the digits from most to least significant

The lookup table can be stored anywhere, in some columns/rows faraway or in another sheet, and then you can also hide that sheet/rows/columns

[image: Table]

Here is the lookup table for the above

| Number | Events |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | None |
| 1 | Reception |
| 2 | Wedding |
| 3 | Wedding, Reception |
| 4 | Sanji |
| 5 | Sanji, Reception |
| 6 | Sanji, Wedding |
| 7 | Sanji, Wedding, Reception |
| 8 | Vesvaar |
| 9 | Vesvaar, Reception |
| 10 | Vesvaar, Wedding |
| 11 | Vesvaar, Wedding, Reception |
| 12 | Vesvaar, Sanji |
| 13 | Vesvaar, Sanji, Reception |
| 14 | Vesvaar, Sanji, Wedding |
| 15 | All |

Comment: While this approach is not scalable, it does offer the flexibility to generate the exact strings that the OP wants;  e.g., ```Wedding & Reception``` and ```Sanji, Wedding & Reception```.

Answer (score 2):

IF You have Office 365 Excel you can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D2:G2,">0")=4,"All",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(D2:G2>0,$D$1:$G$1,"")))
```

It must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

If not then you will need to concat the string on your own:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D2:G2,">0")=4,"All",MID(IF(D2>0,","&$D$1,"")&IF(E2>0,","&$E$1,"")&IF(F2>0,","&$F$1,"")&IF(G2>0,","&$G$1,""),2,200))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Scott. Many thanks for your quick reply. I tried to add the formula but it still doesn't work like I want to. I have attached the excel sheet to the original post to see make it easier to see what has been done. I am still a beginner in Excel so apologies if I am not being clear enough. https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aojtb-lU1PMexWhY7J8C2lHR-n0u

Comment: Which formula did you try and what is it returning?

Comment: I tried this one =IF(COUNTIF(D2:G2,">0")=4,"All",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(D2:G2>0,$D$1:$G$1,""))). It returned with "All" if I kept 1 on "Vesvaar", "Sanji", "Wedding" & "Reception". But if I kept 0 on "Vesvaar", "Sanji", "Reception" but I kept "1" in "Wedding", it returned with #VALUE!

Comment: Are you using Office 365 Excel?  Did you confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: I am using Office 365. Yes I used Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter

Comment: What error did you get?  I am not downloading your file.  I do not download files from unknown sources.

Comment: I have uploaded the sample of the document in here if you wish to have a look 1drv.ms/x/s!Aojtb-lU1PMexWhY7J8C2lHR-n0u

Comment: I just get #VALUE!

Comment: 1. Your sample does not match your picture above, different columns.  You will need to adjust the column references. 2.  If you are using Excel online then this will not work and you will need to use the second equation.  Array formulas do not work with Excel on line.

Comment: I just edited the answer to show that it does work.  You need to adjust to fit your specific needs.

Comment: Hi Scot, I have been using the Excel application and not Excel Online. Apologies for not matching the previous document. I have now uploaded again but with the matching references. https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aojtb-lU1PMexWrkQcY0mOpzSqlq

Comment: @Pratik I do not know what to tell you, try the second equation.  They work for me as witnessed by the pictures in the edit.

Comment: What you did seemed to have worked. Let me try to do it on this side now.

Comment: Hi Scott, I managed to get it to work! The second formula worked! Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Comment: Hi Guys so all of the formulas above work and I appreciate your help!

I am only facing one issue now and that is when I am trying to count how many:

Wedding Only
Wedding & Reception
By using the countif formula:

=COUNTIF(AI2:AI178,"Wedding Only")

=COUNTIF(AI2:AI178,"Wedding & Reception")

But it's showing incorrect values as I believe it's also looking for the Wedding word in every row and it's summing that way.

Is there a way where it can only search for specifically Wedding Only and Wedding & Reception and not double count the words?